# SQL Server Transactions Using REST

Tags: c#, rest, sql-server-2008

I am using a web api to retrieve and update data in a SQL Server database.  The UI receiving the data performs updates, deletes, and inserts prior to requesting a save.

The REST api is setup to perform PUTs, DELETEs, and POSTs to perform the updates.  If, for example, I need to perform a POST and a DELETE separately, how do I contain both operations in a single transaction?

Comment: You can't. It's not just that you're talking about completely different systems. Most services use *multiple* web servers with load balancers. Those requests won't even go to the same server. While there were attempts to use distributed transactions with WS-Transaction in SOAP services, it was just too complex and expensive. Imagine *every* request having to wait for some remote client to remember to commit them

Comment: Every service uses orchestration and conversations instead. Instead of using HTTP as if it was a database interface, services communicate with queues and messages, use idempotent requests (eg identical POSTs won't create duplicates), have specific operations to *compensate* for errors and cancellations instead of rolling back.

Comment: Imagine going to a department store to buy things from 5 departments, with employees in all of them waiting for you to pay first at the ground floor before serving others.  [Starbucks doesn't use two-phase commit](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/docs/IEEE_Software_Design_2PC.pdf) explains why real businesses and real services *don't* use distributed transactions

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick responses.  Wow.  So, unless you have a very simple application, using REST is simply a pipe dream.  That's what I'm hearing.

Comment: Not at all. The exact opposite. After all *no real scaleable service uses distributed transactions*. I'm not talking about REST. No matter the technology, business simply doesn't work that way. Distributed applications don't work that way. The stock exchange, banks, airlines don't work that way. Amazon doesn't work that way.

Comment: I'm saying that you can only use transactions if you have a system where all its components work with a single database server, whose operations only take a short time to complete, and connections are stable, fast and persistent, to avoid losing commit or rollback calls

Comment: REST has it's drawbacks, sometimes (and often enough, IMO) it can be considered too verbose and not very convenient/useful because of that. If this is what you are talking about, then you can look into RPC-based approaches instead of REST (which is resource-based). You can implement such approaches manually or use something like GraphQL.